# How can I check if the cursor is empty?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I have the following sp, where I want to respond to the cursor in case an error does not occur (that's ok) but in the case that it has no rows or is empty, I would like to respond with a code with a description

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test(
    LISTA OUT cursor
)
IS
BEGIN         
    OPEN LISTA FOR
    SELECT 
        rte AS column1,
        r AS column2,
        cs AS column3,
        d AS column4,
        xy.latitud AS column5,
        x AS column6,
        r AS column7,
        'OK' AS column8,
        '0' AS column9
    FROM
     table1;

END sp_test;
```

If the cursor has no rows, I would like to return a message stating that no values were found.

Comment: A cursor doesn't really contain anything. What you're asking is how to predict whether or not a query is going to return anything.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to find out whether cursor is empty or not until you actually **fetch** from it.

This is example based on Scott's `emp` sample table (your code uses table I don't have, and I don't feel like creating one).

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
```

There are several employees in department 10 so this cursor *will* return them:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure sp_test (lista out sys_refcursor) is
  2  begin
  3    open lista for select ename
  4                   from emp
  5                   where deptno = 10;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_rc     sys_refcursor;
  3    l_ename  emp.ename%type;
  4  begin
  5    sp_test (l_rc);
  6    loop
  7      fetch l_rc into l_ename;
  8      if l_rc%notfound then
  9        dbms_output.put_Line('Cursor is empty');
 10        exit;
 11      else
 12         dbms_output.put_line(l_ename);
 13      end if;
 14    end loop;
 15    close l_rc;
 16  end;
 17  /
CLARK
KING
MILLER
Cursor is empty           --> this is result of L_RC%NOTFOUND

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If cursor doesn't return anything at all (note line #5):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure sp_test (lista out sys_refcursor) is
  2  begin
  3    open lista for select ename
  4                   from emp
  5                   where deptno = -10;     --> there's no such department
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.
```

the outcome of anonymous PL/SQL block is just

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_rc     sys_refcursor;
  3    l_ename  emp.ename%type;
  4  begin
  5    sp_test (l_rc);
  6    loop
  7      fetch l_rc into l_ename;
  8      if l_rc%notfound then
  9        dbms_output.put_Line('Cursor is empty');
 10        exit;
 11      else
 12         dbms_output.put_line(l_ename);
 13      end if;
 14    end loop;
 15    close l_rc;
 16  end;
 17  /
Cursor is empty

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

There are different ways you can write such a code; modify it if you think you should, but the general idea remains the same: you'll have to fetch from cursor.

An alternative is to run cursor's `select` statement separately and see whether it returns anything or not, but that's kind of doubtful as you'll have to remember to modify that `select` statement in case you modify the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a cursor row-like variable :

```
Row LISTA%rowtype;
```

You fetch the cursor into the row;

```
fetch LISTA into R;

if LISTA%notfound then 
     -- The cursor is empty
else
     -- The cursor is not empty
end if;
```